# PHP Sorting Multidimensional Associative Array by Key and Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort the following data by the date in the key and the value of Name.

The aim is to a get nice date ordered array with all the Names from the inner array in alphabetical order.

```
Array
(
    [2017-07-27] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Job] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Orange
                        )

                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Job] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Apple
                        )

                )
        )
    [2017-07-22] => Array
        (
            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Job] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Apple
                        )

                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Job] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Orange
                        )

                )
        )
    [2017-07-29] => Array
        (
            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Job] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Orange
                        )

                )

            [11] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Job] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Plumb
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

I'm pretty sure I should be using `array_multisort` but can't quite get the desired results.

Comment: Please use var_export() to print the array, then update the post with the new output.  This will give us a code example that we can copy, paste, and test for you.  Thanks.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must split the code if you want to order on object properties, use the usort function.

Where $arr is your array:

```
uksort($arr, 'dateCmp');
foreach($arr as &$sub){
    usort($sub, 'propCmp');
}

function dateCmp($a, $b){
    return (strtotime($a) < strtotime($b) ? -1 : 1);
}

function propCmp($a, $b){
    return ($a->Job->Name < $b->Job->Name ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Comment: I refined this slightly using ksort($arr, SORT_REGULAR); instead of the user defined function.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,

```
$sorted_vals = array();
ksort($multiArrs);
foreach($multiArrs as $key => $value) { // $multiArrs = your data array
    $columns = null;
    foreach ($value as $index => $element) {
        $columns[] = $element->Job;
    }
    $temp = $value;
    array_multisort($columns, SORT_ASC, $temp);
    $sorted_vals[$key] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: @Sam i changed my answer, please try again my answer.